# create variable based on multiple similar variables in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

My data looks like this (variables `zipid1-zipid13` and variable `hospid` ranges from 1-13:

```
  zipid1 zipid2 zipid3 zipid4 zipid5 zipid6 zipid7 zipid8 zipid9 zipid10 zipid11 zipid12 zipid13 hospid local
1      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
2      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
3      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
4      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
5      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
6      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
```

How can I create a **local** variable = 1 when `zipid1 ==1 & hospid =1, zipid2 == 1 & hospid == 2`.etc. and else = 0 (ie, zipid = hospid)?

I tried `ifelse` but did not work well.

```
for (i in 1:13) {
name = paste0("zipid", i)
local$local <- with(local, ifelse(name == 1 & hospid == i, 1, 0))
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to compute a name, it is almost always easier to use `[[` rather than `$`. `mydata[[paste0("zipid",i)]]` is a construction you can use inside a loop.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how can I assign values to `local` variable using `[[`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a thought:

```
df$local <-  unlist(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x)df[x, paste("zipid", df$hospid, sep = "")[x]]))
```

giving

```
#   zipid1 zipid2 zipid3 zipid4 zipid5 zipid6 zipid7 zipid8 zipid9 zipid10 zipid11 zipid12 zipid13 hospid local
# 1      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     1
# 2      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     1
# 3      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
# 4      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
# 5      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     1
# 6      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     1
```

They way this works is that I take the value in each row of `hospid` then pastes it with `zipid` to make something like `zipid5`. I look up the value in that particular column corresponding to the particular row and check if it's `1`.

---

If there are `NA`s in the data frame these can be removed with `na.omit`. For example, `df <- na.omit(df)` prior to running the code above.

Comment: Thanks @Lyngbakr! I tried this, but it gave me this error: `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "local", value = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,  : 
  replacement has 20728 rows, data has 21129`. My data has 21129 rows.

Comment: @mandy Do you have `NA`s in your data frame? Can you provide a data set with which I can reproduce your error?

Comment: My data has 21129 rows, so it would be hard to reproduce the whole data. I tried replacing all NA to 0s. But still did not work.

Comment: @mandy It wouldn't work because there isn't a `zipid0`. I'll add fix for the `NA`s.

Comment: It worked when I used `na.omit`, thanks so much @Lyngbakr!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the column names `zipid1`, `zipid2`, etc convey payload data, i.e., the number.

My suggestion is to reshape the data from wide to long form, extract the number from the column name, match it with `hospid`, aggregate it by `id`, and merge the result with the original wide format.

Aggregation is done using `toString()` so that we get a valid result in case of multiple matches.

```
library(data.table)
# reshape from wide to long format
melt(setDT(DT), id.vars = c("id", "hospid"), variable.name = "zipid")[
  # turn column names into integer
  , zipid := as.integer(stringr::str_replace(zipid, "zipid", ""))][
    # if value is 1 and zipid and hospid do match then store number
    value == 1L & zipid == hospid, local := hospid][
      # aggregate only mathcing entries by id
      !is.na(local), .(local = toString(local)), by = id][
        # right join with original data
        DT, on = "id"][
          # change column order to meet OP's expectation
          , setcolorder(.SD, names(DT))]
```

> ```
>    id zipid1 zipid2 zipid3 zipid4 zipid5 zipid6 zipid7 zipid8 zipid9 zipid10 zipid11 zipid12 zipid13 hospid local
> 1:  1      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     5
> 2:  2      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     5
> 3:  3      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0       0       0       0       0      5  <NA>
> 4:  4      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5  <NA>
> 5:  5      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     5
> 6:  6      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     5
> ```

#### Edit

By reshaping, the relevant information in `DT` can be condensed to

```
melt(setDT(DT), id.vars = c("id", "hospid"), variable.name = "zipid")[
  , zipid := as.integer(stringr::str_replace(zipid, "zipid", ""))][
    value == 1L]
```

> ```
>    id hospid zipid value
> 1:  2      5     3     1
> 2:  4      5     3     1
> 3:  5      5     3     1
> 4:  1      5     5     1
> 5:  2      5     5     1
> 6:  5      5     5     1
> 7:  6      5     5     1
> 8:  3      5     7     1
> ```

The result is given by

```
melt(setDT(DT), id.vars = c("id", "hospid"), variable.name = "zipid")[
  , zipid := as.integer(stringr::str_replace(zipid, "zipid", ""))][
    value == 1L][
      zipid == hospid]
```

> ```
>    id hospid zipid value
> 1:  1      5     5     1
> 2:  2      5     5     1
> 3:  5      5     5     1
> 4:  6      5     5     1
> ```

So, to combine this with the original data object we can do an update on join:

```
tmp <- 
  melt(setDT(DT), id.vars = c("id", "hospid"), variable.name = "zipid")[
    , zipid := as.integer(stringr::str_replace(zipid, "zipid", ""))][
      value == 1L & zipid == hospid]
DT[tmp, on = "id", local := value][]
```

> ```
>    id zipid1 zipid2 zipid3 zipid4 zipid5 zipid6 zipid7 zipid8 zipid9 zipid10 zipid11 zipid12 zipid13 hospid local
> 1:  1      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     1
> 2:  2      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     1
> 3:  3      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0       0       0       0       0      5    NA
> 4:  4      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5    NA
> 5:  5      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     1
> 6:  6      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     1
> ```

This gives the expected output. No aggregation required.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("id        zipid1 zipid2 zipid3 zipid4 zipid5 zipid6 zipid7 zipid8 zipid9 zipid10 zipid11 zipid12 zipid13 hospid local
1      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
2      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
3      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
4      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
5      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0
6      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0      5     0", drop = "local")
```

Comment: Thanks @Uwe! My concern is that one row can sometimes has two `zipid =1`. For example, `zipid1 == 1 & zipid3 == 1`. I was wondering will the reshaping affect that?

Comment: But `hospid` is only a single number. This will match either 1 (`zipid1`) or 3 (`zipid3`) or none. BTW: I just recognized that my aggregation is not needed, therefore.

Answer (score -1):

name is a vector of strings and in that context are interpreted as strings and not actually as variables, try as `ifelse(get(name)==1 &...`

Comment: Thanks! I tried `get(name)` but still all `local = 0`.